# Cannot access Nullable Dagger2 Android

Tags: android, mvp, dagger-2, android-mvp

I am writing an app where I am using Dagger2 for dependency Injection. I am new to dagger. I am getting confused on how it works and I am not able to figure it out how to use this library. I have tried writing below modules and components with the help of examples in blogs. I have mentioned the purpose of that module. Please correct me if I am wrong.

1. App Module and Component : It should generate a singleton instance across the application and I want to use this instance to access some android  resources

   ```
   @Module
   public class AppModule {

   private BaseApplication baseApplication;

   public AppModule(BaseApplication baseApplication){
       this.baseApplication = baseApplication;
   }

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   BaseApplication providesApplication(){
       return baseApplication;
   }
   }

   @Singleton
   @Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
   public interface AppComponent {
   BaseApplication getBaseApplication();
   }
   ```
2. Instantiation of AppComponent

   ```
   public class BaseApplication extends Application {

   private AppComponent appComponent;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();

       appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new 
   AppModule(this)).build();
   }

   public AppComponent getAppComponent(){
       return appComponent;
   }
   }
   ```

   The above code works fine. I am getting problems in the below code
3. Location Module and Component : Is it Ok if I don't have a constructor 
   for the below module?

   ```
   @Module
   public class LocationModule {

   @IntDef(
           {LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY,
            LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY,
            LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER,
            LocationRequest.PRIORITY_NO_POWER})
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
   public @interface LocationPriority {}

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   @Named("default")
   LocationRequest providesLocationRequest(){
       return new LocationRequest()
               .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
               .setInterval(Constants.LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS)

   .setFastestInterval(Constants.LOCATION_UPDATE_FASTEST_INTERVAL_MS)

   .setSmallestDisplacement(Constants.LOCATION_UPDATE_DISPLACEMENT_METERS);
   }

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   @Named("custom")
   LocationRequest providesCustomLocationRequest(int interval, int 
   fastestInterval, @LocationPriority int priority, float updateDisplacement) {
       return new LocationRequest()
               .setPriority(priority)
               .setInterval(interval)
               .setFastestInterval(fastestInterval)
               .setSmallestDisplacement(updateDisplacement);
   }

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   LocationSettingsRequest providesLocationSettingsRequest(LocationRequest 
   locationRequest){
        return new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
                .build();
   }

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   FusedLocationProviderClient providesFusedLocationClient(BaseApplication 
   baseApplication){
       return LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(baseApplication);
   }

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   SettingsClient providesSettingsClient(BaseApplication baseApplication){
       return LocationServices.getSettingsClient(baseApplication);
   }
   }


   @Singleton
   @Component(modules = {LocationModule.class, AppModule.class})
   public interface LocationComponent {

   **Do we Really need a method here?**
   void inject(GetLocationUseCase getLocationUseCase);

   }
   ```

I am getting the following error

> error: cannot access Nullable   class file for
>   javax.annotation.Nullable not found

after using @Inject in below class. If I remove @Inject the error goes away.

```
public final class GetLocationUseCase implements 
UseCaseContract.BusinessLogic {


UseCaseContract.Mediator mediator;

@Inject
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClientl;

@Override
public void onInitialize() {

    BaseApplication application = mediator.requestUserContext();

    DaggerLocationComponent.builder().appModule(new 
AppModule(application)).locationModule(new 
LocationModule()).build().inject(this);

}
```

Why am I getting that error? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some missing code snippit. Do u get error while compiling or while execution?

Comment: I am getting it during compile time i.e when I click Run app in android studio

Answer (score 4):

You need to add missing modules in your Component ..
For example, you will get this error if you remove NetModule from below

```
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetModule.class, MainModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
```

...

Answer (score 1):

In case someone like me out there. I forgot to add `@Provides` annotation to the Dagger Module.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a class with `@Inject` annotated constructor which extended another 3rd party class which had `@Nullable` annotation on one of the method parameters. Once I removed this extension everything started to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting about 1 day on this issue, I found out that I need to temporarily add `findbugs` dependency like this:

`implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'`

Then dagger will print the actual error.